# What does mx:target do in Flex 3?

Tags: flex3, target, addchild, states

There is [an example on Adobe livedocs for using states](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/states/AddChild.html):

```
<!-- Define one view state, in addition to the base state.-->
    <mx:states>
        <mx:State name="Register">
            <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{loginForm}" position="lastChild">
                <mx:target>
                    <mx:FormItem id="confirm" label="Confirm:">
                        <mx:TextInput/>
                    </mx:FormItem>
                </mx:target>
            </mx:AddChild>
            <mx:SetProperty target="{loginPanel}" name="title" value="Register"/>
            <mx:SetProperty target="{loginButton}" name="label" value="Register"/>
            <mx:SetStyle target="{loginButton}" 
                name="color" value="blue"/>
            <mx:RemoveChild target="{registerLink}"/>
            <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{spacer1}" position="before">
                <mx:target>
                    <mx:LinkButton id="loginLink" label="Return to Login" click="currentState=''"/>
                </mx:target>
            </mx:AddChild>
        </mx:State>
    </mx:states>
```

I haven't been able to find the purpose of mx:target in

```
<mx:AddChild relativeTo="{spacer1}" position="before">
                <mx:target>
                    <mx:LinkButton id="loginLink" label="Return to Login" click="currentState=''"/>
                </mx:target>
            </mx:AddChild>
```

Does anyone know what that does and if it is necessary? It seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: Good question. I hope you get an answer to this, but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I over-thought this one a bit.  Turns out target is just the target child you are adding and that is just another way to define it as opposed to defining it as an inline attribute to the AddChild tag.